# build succeeded but did not produce the class "cloudfunction" specified as the function target

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I am trying to build successfully a cloud function in java with cloud build.
Cloud build returns me this error at the end of the steps

> Deployment failure:
> Build failed: build succeeded but did not produce the class "cloudfunction" specified as the function target: Error: class not found: cloudfunction; Error ID: d2301784

java code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CloudfunctionApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CloudfunctionApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
    return value -> value.toUpperCase();
}
}
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'cloudfunction', '--source=.' , '--project=[PROJECT_ID]', '-- 
trigger-http', '--region=europe-west3','--runtime=java11']
```

pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>cloudfunction</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>cloudfunction</name>
<description>CloudFunction project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The cloud build deployed it but with errors
[GCP cloud functions screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2RGB.png)

Could you suggest me if i am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The error states that cloudfunction class is not found so on your yaml file you need to pass the actual class name which is `CloudfunctionApplication`

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'CloudfunctionApplication', '--source=.' , '--project=[PROJECT_ID]', '-- 
trigger-http', '--region=europe-west3','--runtime=java11']
```

Comment: I tried inserting the actual class name but the issue remain build succeeded but did not produce the class "CloudfunctionApplication" - @Prany

Comment: just noticed that in pom.xml artifactId is still cloudfunction, can you try by changing to  CloudfunctionApplication

Comment: THere is one example here - https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-java

Comment: The issue persist changing the artifactId, i have added an entry-point to the yaml file **--entry-point=com.example.cloudfunction.CloudfunctionApplication** but this not resolve **build succeeded but did not produce the class "com.example.cloudfunction.CloudfunctionApplication"**

Comment: Only thing I can think of is the yaml file. Can you try with this yaml example here - https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-functions#continuous_deployment

Comment: I tried following the QuickStart tutorial and with a maven project it worked! There is a way to create a cloud function using spring boot Application. I tried following this guide https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/html/gcp.html#:~:text=The%20Google%20Cloud%20Functions%20adapter,for%20Java%20or%20on%20GCP.  but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the entry point as below:

```
--entry-point=org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher
```

[reference](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/html/gcp.html#_background_functions)

Sample Cloudbuild.yaml

```
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  args:
  - gcloud
  - functions
  - deploy
  - email-function
  - --region=us-central1
  - --source=target/deploy
  - --entry-point=org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher
  - --runtime=java11
  - --memory=512MB
  - --trigger-topic=mytopic
```